# Help finding CSS problem in FireFox

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

I have a page that I'm working on that has the following HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TileTabs</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/veramono.css" type="text/css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/element_sequentials.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>
            TileTabs.com
        </h1>
    </header>

    <div id="content">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="images/sites/truncated/google_trunc.png" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/sites/truncated/google_trunc.png" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/sites/truncated/google_trunc.png" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/sites/truncated/google_trunc.png" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a> | <a href="about.html">About</a> | <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
body {
    background: #333;
    font-family: 'BitstreamVeraSansMonoRoman', 'Myriad-Pro', 'Myriad', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 100px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-shadow: 2px 3px 3px #292929;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 2px 3px 3px #292929;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
}

header {
    width: 920px;
    background: #666;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;


}

#content {
    width: 920px;
    height: 600px;
    background: #666;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    width: 920px;
    background: #666;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;    
}

ul {
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 125px 60px 0;
}
```

veramano.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BitstreamVeraSansMonoRoman';
    src: url('veramono-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('veramono-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('veramono-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('veramono-webfont.svg#webfonttPkD6dqa') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

For some reason, everything looks terribly off in FireFox, but not in Chrome.  I'm running Mac OS X, I've seen that *sometimes* that matters.

I'm trying to upload this live for you guys, sorry for the temporary inconvenience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed by adding `display:block;` 
in footer's css.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It worked to fix both the header and footer elements.  I'm sure this is quite basic, but could you please explain why this was necessary?

Comment: in HTML5 These type of elements are known as block-level elements and they require display:block